# Change Taxonomy Page to display first node in full

Tags: taxonomy-terms

By default in Drupal 7, a taxonomy page lists the titles of all the nodes that have been tagged with that term.

Is there any way to make it so the page shows just the first node that is tagged with that term?

I want it so the first node is displayed in full (Ideally, the term page should automatically take the user to the first node).

I know you can use Views to override a taxonomy and control what content is shown. However, I would like to do this without views (i.e. so the user is seeing the acutal node as opposed to a view of the node).

I also want it to happen automatically (i.e. for every term, the first node should displayed. The admin of the site should not have to manually set up this state for each individual term).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to enable the "Taxonomy term" view in Views:
[image: enabling taxonomy term view]
Add and offset of 1 to the page view:
[image: editing pager offset]

And then add and Attachment display that has a pager with an Offset of 0 and an Items per page as 1. On the attachment you can switch the Format to show full nodes instead of teasers.
[image: adding attachment display]

This will work "automatically" for all Taxonomy terms. The reason this works is that the view takes an argument of the taxonomy term in the URL.

[image: taxonomy view argument]

It overrides Drupal core's url for Taxonomy terms and uses the view as a replacement.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. However, that solution uses a view as the replacement which is something I didn't want to do (see opening question). The reason for this is that my node uses custom theming in a node tpl file, which wont be carried over to the view.

Comment: If you set the view mode to "Full content" for the attachment view it will display the output of the node tpl file.

Comment: That works brilliantly, except it shows the first two results. How can I limit it so it just displays the first one.

Comment: Is that for the Attachment? It should show one result if you add offset '1' and results '1'. Did that work?

Comment: Thanks for your continued help. For the attachment I have: offset 1, results 1. For the page, I have Items per page 10, offset, 1. Is that correct? With these settings, it displays the first three.

Comment: Sorry, for the attachment it should be offset "0". Basically you are telling it to display the first result in the attachment, then offset by 1 result, and display the remaining results in the page display.